# Syzygies and Free Resolutions

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am going to attend a workshop on Syzygies and Free Resolutions
and want to prepare for that. I haven't had introduction to the 
subject but I studied first course in commutative algebra.
I request you to guide and suggest books for my preparation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does MPLW mean?

Comment: http://atmschools.org/2012/mplw/syzygies-and-free-resolutions

Answer (score 2):

A pre-release version of Eisenbud's "Geometry of Syzygies" is freely available on the internet. [www.msri.org/people/staff/de/book.pdf](http://www.msri.org/people/staff/de/book.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I found the review

Gardner, R. "Review of ``Invariant theory'', by J.A. Springer".
*Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* 2 (1980) 246--256.

helpful for its background on the origin of resolutions. It can be downloaded from the AMS web site [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1980-02-01/S0273-0979-1980-14739-4/S0273-0979-1980-14739-4.pdf).